# Dynamically using Android intent

Tags: android, android-intent, fragment

Here is my grid view fragment, i'm planning on adding 50 drawable items to the grid, my problem is onclick method. How can intent to new Activity class for these 50 items. i do have a onClick method which is working fine, but adding 50 case statement is painful, is there any way to dynamically intent 50 activity class depending on their class name.

public class FragMent1 extends Fragment {

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview,container,false);
        GridView gridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(getActivity())); // uses the view to get the context instead of getActivity().
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position,
                    long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                   Intent n = null;

                      switch(position){
                      case 0:
                         n = new Intent(getActivity(), abc.class);
                            getActivity().startActivity(n);
                            break;
                      case 1:
                           n = new Intent(getActivity(), bcd.class);
                            getActivity().startActivity(n);
                            break;
                      case 2:
                           // n = new Intent(getActivity(), cbe.class);
                            getActivity().startActivity(n);
                            break;

                     }
            }
        });
      return view;
    }
     @Override
     public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
     }
    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private Context mContext;

        public  ImageAdapter(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return mThumbIds.length;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

         public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                ImageView imageView;
                if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
                    imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
                    imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(500, 500));
                    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                    imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
                } else {
                    imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
                }

                imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
                return imageView;
            }

        private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
                R.drawable.car, 
                R.drawable.dabangg,
                R.drawable.dabangg,
                R.drawable.car,
                R.drawable.car, 
                R.drawable.dabangg
        };

        }

}
```

Comment: If you have 50+ Activities, you should probably rethink your design.

Comment: each item is linked to youtube fragment. if you see in my youtube class it has arraylist in onInitializationsucess method. not sure how can i pass those array list values, because each one has different values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can pass in a key to the activity based on the item they selected in the grid as an intent extra. Grab the passed in value, and do whatever needs to be done.

Example:

```
 gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position,
                long arg3) {
                         Myobject obj=(MyObject)adapter.getItem(position);
                         Intent intent=new Intent(CurrentActivity.this,NextActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("MY_KEY",obj.getMyValue());
                         startActivity(intent);
                 }
        }
    });
```

Then in your onCreate method of your next activity you do

```
int defaultValue=-1;
int value=getIntent().getIntExtra("MY_KEY", defaultValue);
switch (value){
case 0:
break
```

}

and so on

Comment: hi KennyC, thanks for the reply can you please show an example please? that how can i implement it in my code.

Comment: thanks but can you please explain? whats "onCreate method of your next activity" doing? can you please show me a example of case 0 where i can use drawable and which also have My_key value. i'm sorry but i'm fairly new to these.

Comment: Instead of having an activity for every different case, you would only have 1 activity and based on the value you pass in with the intent extra, you do whatever needs to be done for that case. Next activity is just an arbitrary name, you can call it whatever you want.